# Cannot log into Cinnamon after deleting ~/.config

Tags: cinnamon

After I removed "./.config" from Home folder, I can not log in to the cinnamon session:

```
failed to load session "cinnamon"
```

What do I do?

xsession-error:

```
Xsession: X session started for tux at Fri Oct 26 06:35:58 IRST 2012
localuser:tux being added to access control list
Setting IM through im-switch for locale=en_US.
Start IM through /etc/X11/xinit/xinput.d/all_ALL linked to /etc/X11/xinit/xinput.d/default.
Failed to connect to the VirtualBox kernel service
Failed to connect to the VirtualBox kernel service
Failed to connect to the VirtualBox kernel service
Failed to connect to the VirtualBox kernel service
```

I am runing Cinnamon on a local machine, no on Virtualbox. but virtualbox is installed for some usage.
!?

Comment: I already disabled gnome-setting-daemon for problems in Mate and forgotten restore it to primary state, The problem solved with this: sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-settings-daemon.desktop.disabled /etc/xdtostart/gnome-settings-daemon.desktop

Comment: If that solved your problem you should add an answer that includes that information. That will help to make it easier to find, especially for newer users.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest reinstall Cinnamon.log in recue mode pressing shift booting system, choose Recovery mode from grub boot loader options.

First Completely uninstall Cinnamon By

```
sudo apt-get --Purge cinnamon
```

Reinstall it by

```
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

Comment: Didn't work your suggest.

Comment: Try to purge Virtualbox also.